# What is the reason i don't get all the elements in the tuple when i print args. Here args[0] prints 2 instead of 1.

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    a=[args,kwargs]
    print args
    print type(args)
    print type(kwargs)
    print a
__init__(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Output -

```
(2, 3, 4, 5)
<type 'tuple'>
<type 'dict'>
[(2, 3, 4, 5), {}]
```

Where do 1 from the tuple args go ? On printing args it should have returned (1,2,3,4,5) instead of (2,3,4,5)

Comment: 1 went to `self` since `__init__` isn't on a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `self` would pass as any other argument since `__init__` is not bound to any class instance. `self` takes `1`.

Note that `self` is only a convention used for naming class instances in the class body and has no special significance when used outside the body of a class or method. It is only a name.

You should also avoid using `___thisnotation__` with non special methods to avoid ambiguity.

`__init__` should therefore be defined in the body of a class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        a=[args,kwargs]
        print args
        print type(args)
        print type(kwargs)
        print a
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are right, but perhaps this will better explain:

```
def foo(bar, *args):
    print('Bar is {bar}'.format(bar=bar))
    print('args is {args}'.format(args=args))

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# Output:
# Bar is 1
# args is (2, 3, 4, 5)
```

The confusing part is that you named your function `__init__` and named the first parameter `self`. Those names are common in class constructors, and when you invoke a constructor (or any method on an object), there's an extra first parameter that points to the object. So this code would do what you expect:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(args)

foo = Foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# Output:
# (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stick your method in a class and get the expected output:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        a=[args,kwargs]
        print args
        print type(args)
        print type(kwargs)
        print a

Example(1,2,3,4,5)
```